# Choosing a DB connection

Tags: architecture, database-connection, saas

### Hypothetical System

Consider a system which exposes a single web UI, but which utilizes multiple instances of the same database schema. Suppose that each user belongs to some larger entity, call it an "organization", and each organization has its own instance of the database. When the user logs in, the system should determine which instance of the DB to use.

Such a system appears on the surface to require connection strings to be stored in a centralized database. At first glance, that a centralized database is still required by the system seems to defeat the purpose of each organization having its own database. Secondly, I have read that it is inadvisable to store connection strings in a database in the first place. As a final observation, it seems naive to me that mapping user login information to a connection string is the only way for the system to determine which database instance to use, but I can't think of an alternative.

### My questions are as follows:

1. Am I correct in my initial assessment that this hypothetical system would, in fact, require a centralized database to map user login information to the connection string corresponding to the organization to which that user belongs?
2. If a centralized database is required, does that necessarily defeat the purpose of each organization having its own separate instance of the database?
3. Is it really such a bad idea to store connection strings in a database? Why? What questions and concerns should be considered when storing connection strings in the database?
4. Is mapping the login info to a connection string really the only way for the website to know which database instance to use? What other techniques are out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, there could be alternatives, depending on the user identifier. E.g., if you use email addresses to identify users and can ensure that each organization uses only a set of known (and unique) domains, you could select the right database on the domain part alone. You could store the domain-database information in a separate central DB. Note that you could simply store a string with the DB name (not all connection details) in this central DB, the details could come from some property file at startup time (mapping DB names to connection details).

   Alternatively you could just query all DBs with the user credentials until you've found the "right" DB.
2. That's hard to say. If the central DB is just containing the login information (and e.g. other cross-organizational data), the organization-specific DBs could still contain data that is, well, specific to the organization. E.g., it might have slightly different schema, it might demand encryption of some sort or you have different access restrictions for users per database etc. I've seen requests from organizations (clients) that specifically demand that there data is stored "separately" from other organizations, due to security concerns.
3. (+4.) You don't *need* connection strings to be stored in some central database to support this scheme. You could fire up connection pool(s) for all organization DBs at startup, so you don't need to handle the connection details at (a later) run-time. The big issue to consider is security: what could happen if somebody can get access to the connection details? He could probably use that to retrieve all data from the other DBs. So it boils down to how good you can protect this connection data, e.g., you almost certainly don't want this information to be stored unencrypted in some DB.

Comment: As a point of clarification on your answer to my first question, is that a thing where the database would be determined by examining the destination URL? More specifically, if the web UI was written in C# using MVC, would the login code simply examine `Request.Url` and choose the DB connection based on the subdomain? Or were you referring to some other technique?

Comment: There is a difference between establishing a DB connection and using it. IMHO, opening a connection is best handled with a [connection pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool). When you have multiple DBs to connect to, you probably need one pool per DB. You need some way to determine which pool (i.e. which DB) to talk to, in my answer I assumed you have some mapping 'email-domain: database name' -- this could be stored in your (central) DB. You would then have another mapping 'database name:connection pool' (basically a hashmap), which you would build at runtime.